# Linux : Ethtool Command

Tags: linux

I am trying to get interface speed by using command ethtool_cmd_speed(&cmd);
But when i try to compile it , it is throwing error like
undefined reference to `ethtool_cmd_speed'. I want to know is there any other command which can be used to get interface speed ?

And it is compiling for newer version of linux, but when i try to compile it in older version, it is giving error. so can anyone tell me how can i get speed of interface ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appear as bug in linux sources, or incompatibility of sources with your current compiler.

If you look into [sources of ethtool_cmd_speed](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/ethtool.h#L47), you can see it's just few lines:

```
static inline __u32 ethtool_cmd_speed(const struct ethtool_cmd *ep)
{
    return (ep->speed_hi << 16) | ep->speed;
}
```

Try to add this function into your app, renaming it.

Answer (score 0):

An *undefined reference* means you're not linking with a required library.  However, the function in question is defined as `static __inline__`, as already noted, so there is no symbol to link against.  That means you've included the wrong header or perhaps declared the function yourself.  Just include `linux/ethtool.h`.